# How to "data-dismiss" bootstrap on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, model, bootstrap-modal

My Code is as below :

```
   <div class="tr">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-modal mr10" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <%= button_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary", "data-dismiss" => "modal" %>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= button_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary", "data-dismiss": "modal", "aria-hidden": "true" %>`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.